# ros_control requirements

Tags: ros-control, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Required info:
Distro: Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04
The robot is running on a gaming laptop and brings up **kinect2_bridge**, **roboclaw_node** and the **rplidar_node** and sends data over home wifi.
I view the data on a remote PC via RVIZ.

Most of my experience up to this point has been with simulated robots and gazebo. I have gone through the tutorials on making a real robot and have a fully built bot IRL. It teleoperates fine and I can make maps, though my odometry appears to suffer from inaccuracy. I am trying to eliminate issues that might be causing it, such as simply not having configured my robot properly.

I have read through the wiki pages on the navigation stack and I would like to better understand at what point **ros_control** becomes necessary in a robot build please. I am referring to this diagram: [image: image description].

My robot has two motors with quadrature encoders being driven by a roboclaw motion control board. it uses the custom **roboclaw_node** which subscribes to cmd_vel and publishes **odom** plus some motor status messages. It has its own PID control built in.

At what stage would the roboclaw_node appear in the attached diagram? I am not sure if I am missing something from my build. As mentioned, at present I am teleoperating the robot in order to make maps. I am not navigating yet.

This is the urdf representation of my real robot [image: image description] Now If that were in gazebo, I would put libdiffdrive in the .gazebo file and set the front caster to have zero friction and gazebo would take care of creating robot movement, which is reflected in RVIZ. However now of course, RVIZ only has the drive wheel encoder odometry to inform its position. Is RVIZ really giving me an accurate representation of movement if there is no model to inform it how the three wheels, 2 x drive plus 1 x caster, interact?

Is ros_control and RobotHW always needed in every build? Or does the roboclaw node effectively take care of everything?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321347/ros_control-requirements/) by [Wireline](https://answers.ros.org/users/31862/wireline/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2019-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some comments (slightly pedantic, but I feel important):

> I would like to better understand at what point ros_control becomes necessary in a robot build

never. Using `ros_control` is a choice, and robots can (and have) been built without it and function perfectly fine.

> [..] RVIZ only has the drive wheel encoder odometry to inform its position [..] Is RVIZ really giving me an accurate representation of movement [..]

Please understand: RViz does not do *anything* else but visualise data streams. It does not calculate odometry, or the pose of your robot. It's not even giving you "an accurate representation of movement". It just renders a 3D model at a certain 6D pose. But all of that information has to come from outside, as RViz is just a consumer of data.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wireline](https://answers.ros.org/users/31862/wireline/) on 2019-04-18**:
Thank you, that answers my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-18**:
Note that reusing `ros_control` can definitely be beneficial (as certainly the controllers it provides can save you a lot of work), but it's never a requirement.